# Finding id with Rows that appeared once in a big dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset and i want to find ID's which appeared only once in whole dataset along with their respective rows.

```
OrderTraffic1<-OrderTraffic[(duplicated(OrderTraffic$wayId, fromLast = FALSE)| 
            duplicated(OrderTraffic$wayId, fromLast = TRUE)),]
```

by this code i removed rows in which respective wayId appeared only once,but i want to store those removed values by some other command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the index by negating the original index

```
i1 <- (duplicated(OrderTraffic$wayId, fromLast = FALSE)| 
                duplicated(OrderTraffic$wayId, fromLast = TRUE))
i2 <- !i1
```

---

Or another option is `setdiff` with the original dataset to get the rows that are not in the 'OrderTraffic1'

```
library(dplyr)
setdiff(OrderTraffic, OrderTraffic1)
#    wayId val
#1     2   3
```

or using `fsetdiff` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fsetdiff(as.data.table(OrderTraffic), as.data.table(OrderTraffic1))
#   wayId val
#1:     2   3
```

#### data

```
OrderTraffic <- data.frame(wayId = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), val = 1:5)
```